# Prompting Multiple inputs on a Single line

Tags: java

I have a question. I know you can prompt a user multiple times with scanner as so

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String First;
        String Last;
        int Age;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is the First name of person?");
        First = input.next();
        System.out.print("What is the Last name of person?");
        Last = input.next();  
        System.out.print("What is the Age of person?");
        Age = input.next(); 
}
```

But is there a way there to prompt all in one line?

For example I want to enter

```
Console-What is the First, Last, and Age of the person?
User- First Last Age
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Java variables start with a lower case letter by convention (yours look like class names). Second, this

```
Age = input.next();
```

gives you a compiler error. Because `Age` is an `int`. You can certainly split the single line as others have suggested, but you can also construct a [`Scanner(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.lang.String%29) and use it with something like

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the first name last name and age of the person: ");
System.out.println("(first last age)");
String line = input.nextLine();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);
String first = scan.next();
String last = scan.next();
int age = scan.nextInt();
System.out.printf("Person: %s, %s (%d)%n", last, first, age);
```

Comment: Ah Thank you for this!, I have a general question though.
I have a loop that asks for how many people I need, but why do I have declare a new scanner within the loop?

Comment: @YummyTree You don't have to use a `Scanner`, but the `Scanner` producing symbols from a `String` is an easy way to get the behavior you're after. Alternatively (for example), you might `split` and `parseInt()` the third term.

Comment: Ah gotcha! So with in the loop I can technically use the array and split method!

Comment: @YummyTree Yes. Which is why I sad *You can certainly split the single line as others have suggested.*

Answer (score 0):

Grab a line and split the string:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("What is the First, Last, and Age of the person?");
String line = input.nextLine();
String[] parts = line.split(" ");
if(parts.length < 3){
    //error, ask again
}
else{
    String first = parts[0];
    String last = parts[1];
    String age = parts[2];
}
```